# Dynamically set page value when sending virtual page view to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to dynamically set the page path before sending a virtual pageview to Google Analytics.

I am using wordpress multisite, but I imagine this is a problem on other platforms.  For example, I have a bunch of sites

- rooturl.com/somesite1/
- rooturl.com/somesite2/
- rooturl.com/somesite3/

When I send a virtual pageview

`gaplusu('send', 'pageview', '/exit');`

The pageview in GA shows as /exit but I need it to show as /somesite1/exit or /somesite2/exit

I'm not sure how to pass the site slug or any other dynamic info into the gaplusu function

**Here is the functions I'm currently using:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
     //gravityform lead capture
    jQuery('#gform_submit_button_8')
        .click(function ($) {
            gaplusu('set', 'title', 'Purchase Exit');
            gaplusu('send', 'pageview', '/exit');
        });
});
```

The pageview in GA shows as /exit but I need it to show as /somesite1/exit or /somesite2/exit

Comment: Is somesiteX available in some form, e.g. global variable, or is it also the question, how to determine the current subdirectory?

Comment: somesiteX could be deduced by parsing the url with regex. somesiteX could also be set to a cookie using php.  Not sure which method would be more accessible to jQuery